# TranslateAnimation not work at the first time

Tags: android, animation, visibility

I want to visible/gone button with animation right to left /left to right by clicking on it's row,
and this is my code to set it visible:

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(button.getWidth(),0,0,0);
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
button.startAnimation(animate);
```

and  for gone :

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,button.getWidth(),0,0);
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
button.startAnimation(animate);
```

By default, button is gone. For the first time, when I click the row, button has become visible but without animation. After that it works properly. Why for first time animation does not work ??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the animation, call `button.setY(button.getWidth())` to set its position.

Comment: Worse than before :(

Comment: I will need your layout code that contains the button to see how you place it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Delay to work it for first time

```
       TranslateAnimation animate1 = new TranslateAnimation(
                    0,                 // fromXDelta
                    0,                 // toXDelta
                    0,  // fromYDelta
                    binding.saveCardview.getMeasuredHeight());                // toYDelta
                animate1.setDuration(500);
                animate1.setFillAfter(true);
                binding.saveCardview.startAnimation(animate1);

                final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do something after 100ms
                        binding.saveCardview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 500);
```